# redshift view for loop data

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have audit data which i need to create report on top of this, 
source data is in Redshift Table in below shape with sample data

[image: source data]

i need to write a view which will be a report  based on the source data

[image]

can anyone please guide how i can iterate on some field like here amp,gmp,user field to create report 
note : flag Y is the latest new.
Appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: Please try to  avoid images and put content as text. Refer to this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852/easier-way-to-represent-db-tables-when-asking-db-questions

Answer (score 0):

I think you want window functions:

```
select t.*
from  (select amp, gmp, delivery_date as new_value,
             lag(delivery_date) over (partition by amp, gmp order by rec_start_dt, rec_end_dt) as  old_value,
             updatedby, rec_start_dt
       from t
      ) t
where old_value is not null;
```